# Set a template on a custom post in the plugin

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, php, page-template

I looked at some answers and didn't help

I'm trying the next section (right away) but it returns the template if errors in WordPress's built-in function lines. Like get_header ()

```
add_filter('template_include', 'my_custom_template');

function my_custom_template($single) {

global $post;

/* Checks for single template by post type */
if ( $post->post_type == 'simulators' ) {
        return SIMULATOR_URI . 'inc/themes/admin/single-simulators.php';
    }

return $single;

}
```

Basically, the template is already listed in WordPress templates, is there an easy way to set it as a custom post template?

Comment: You don't really need that custom code because you could just create `single-simulators.php` in the root theme folder, and WordPress would use that template when displaying single posts of the `simulators` type. See the [developer docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) for more options on single post *templates*.

Comment: I want everything to be in the plugin without the need for a theme change

Comment: Ok, but what's not working in your code? That filter is indeed one way how one can override templates in WordPress theme or plugin.